# React: no output from constant object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React Native. I am using hooks but in `dishes.name` it is not showing any output. Why?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import {DISHES} from '../shared/dishes';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MenuComponent from './MenuComponent'

const MainComponents=()=>{
    const [dishes,adddish]=useState([DISHES]);
       return(
          <View style={{padding:100}}>    
              <Text>
                   {dishes.name}
             </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
export default MainComponents;



export const DISHES =
[
    {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        featured: true,
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'                    
     },
     {
        id: 1,
        name:'Zucchipakoda',
        image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'',
        price:'1.99',
        featured: false,
        description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name:'Vadonut',
        image: 'images/vadonut.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'New',
        price:'1.99',
        featured: false,
        description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        label:'',
        price:'2.99',
        featured: false,
        description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms'
    }
];
```

Comment: What is `dishes`? It looks like its an array. And arrays don't have a property `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access property ".name" of your array, which does not exist.

You need to loop through the array and get the property ".name" of each object in it. After that you need to put JSX tag ' Text ' outside of each 'name' and put them in an array again.

```
  const MainComponents = () => {
        const [dishes, adddish] = useState(DISHES);
        function renderDishes() {
            const DishesJSX = [];
            DISHES.map(eachDish => {
                DishesJSX.push(<Text>{eachDish.name}</Text>);
            });
            return DishesJSX;
        }
        return <View style={{ padding: 100 }}>{renderDishes()}</View>;
    };
    export default MainComponents;
```